# Ignorance towards new comers

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

I am a newbie here in stack exchange. This site is very informative. So, I tried to contribute with the little knowledge I have.

So, I posted [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/373574/174490) answer after reading the question, all the other answers and the comments of the OP.

I really don't know where I've done wrong. But, I am downvoted. I confirmed from the teacher after that : he said it was good enough.

I think this is the dark side of PSE that they don't value the new users here.

Does this happen with most of the new comers ?

In case if I've made anything wrong in my answer, please point out. I'll be pleased.

Comment: English is not my first language. So, sorry for any grammatical errors.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here, sorry. "Share your thoughts" is exceedingly vague. Could you perhaps ask something a little more specific?

Comment: Edited as requested

Comment: I think everyone here has gotten downvotes. No big deal...

Comment: *"I think this is the dark side of PSE that they don't value the new users here."* - you had my attention until I read this.  If one downvote brings you to this conclusion, I doubt that you'll flourish here.  If you hover over the downvote button, you find the hover text "this answer is not useful".  That's a judgment call isn't it?  If someone here judges your answer to be 'not useful', that's their judgment and they are certainly free to express it just as surely as you are free to ignore it and give it no further thought whatsoever.  Don't sweat over the things beyond your span of control.

Comment: I agree with @AlfredCentauri but much less patiently: to conclude based on a single downvote that the site doesn't value new users is pretty thick: everyone started as a new user.  Moreover, I don't like the suggestion that this is in any way related to "ignorance" on the part of anyone.   Lastly, I would not have downvoted the answer to a pretty mundane question like this one, although the answer the doesn't add much: I would not have upvoted it either.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few possible factors. (I didn't vote on the question/answers though, this is pure speculation)

It doesn't seem immediately clear to me what you're trying to say in the answer.  I can follow some of it; but it doesn't seem direct in how it addressed the question asked.

Also, the question was already over a year old and had an accepted answer, so there's even more reason to make sure what you say is really clear about what it is adding.

Most importantly, (as mentioned in a comment) it's really not a big deal.  That vote means that someone found your answer not-useful.  It's only one person's opinion.  (see for example [this help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) on the voting model; how it is a democracy, and reasons why one might choose to downvote)

Comment: It would be useful to mention that the ones who downvote are kept secret. It would be useful to condition the downvote of writing a comment of why the post is bad in the voter's eyes.

Comment: @DanielC that's been proposed a thousand times over on [meta.se] and resoundly rejected each time.

Comment: Then I see no reason to consider a change to my downvoted post, just because it got a minus, or maybe more.

Comment: @DanielC, that's exactly the correct conclusion; don't give an anonymous downvote a second thought; it isn't worth it.

Comment: @DanielC If people spent their time commenting on downvotes and bad posts the site would rapidly become non-functional.  This is a case where ignorance is bliss.